# Are nested views in MVC possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am experimenting the MVC, I am attempting to make a example stock control panel to teach myself the basics of working with MVC and Entity Framework.

I have a database with two tables, Categories & Products. On my MVC site i want to be able to browse the rows in these tables, where Categories share a one to many relationship with products.

I currently have it set up were you can view/edit/delete categories in MVC, but now i want to be able to view/edit/delete products within categories and i do not know how to go about it.

My current URL structure for it goes `<URL>/categories` i would like to follow this up with accessing a list of products within a category by navigating to `<URL>/categories/<category id>/Products` to display a list of all products associated with that category, and then `<URL>/categories/<category id>/Products/delete/<product id>` etc to manipulate them.

I've looked at adding custom routes to the RegisterRoutes function but i do not think i have the understanding to do this, as i created this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Products",// Route name
    "Category/{categoryid}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",// URL with parameters
    new { categoryid = "", controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

which just seems completely wrong, and i have no idea how the relationship betwen the URL ad the default parameters even work, or how this links to the folder structure in the project.

Is what i am attempting to do wrong? should there be some other way i do it? any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of MVC? Attribute routing makes this very simple, though it's possible either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically we would have a controller for `Categories` and `Products`.  The `Categories` controller would look like

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View(db.Categories());
    }
```

This gives you a url of `<URL>/categories` to give a list of categories.

Then you'd have an `Edit` `ActionResult` to take a CategoryID and view the details of the `Category`  this url would be `<URL>/categories/1`

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
    var model = db.Categories.Find(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

On the edit screen we would show the list of `Products` associated with the `Category` in table/grid whatever  with `Add` `Edit` and `Delete` buttons/links.  If the `Add` button/link is clicked we redirect to the `Products` controller `Create` action and pass the `CategoryID` in as a parameter.  That url would look like `<URL>/products/create/1` and the action would look like

```
public ActionResult Create(int id) {
    var model = new Product(){ CategoryID = id};
    return View(model);
}
```

If you clicked `Edit` on a `Product` from the `Category` edit view you would just call the `Edit` action on the `Product` controller and pass the `ProductID` in as a parameter.  that url would look like `<URL>/products/edit/1` and the action would look like

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
    var model = new db.Products.Find(id)
    return View(model);
}
```

Everyone has their preferences but I've created some pretty complex MVC sites without ever having to modify the default route or create new ones.

Comment: This was my initial thought but i believed having the products nested in the categories would be seen as "neater", i'll return to doing it that way. Thanks.